# disable Secure Renegotiation in apache httpd 2.4

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We have been reported that is on our website/domain hosted via apache httpd 2.4 proxy.

```
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: D99A3E3FE44E02D6CFED853DDEF92E8ECAE7F2444D180887B6FCCDB843B0D2A6
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: F3D1094E8EABE09492CF7FFDB79F2F566CA3F87473523164A62ECED7D4DA57B07B5317BC73DB12B8DFDACDE739758682
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1597139113
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
R
RENEGOTIATING
```

and asked to turn off the same, not sure if SSLInsecureRenegotiation is same as Secure Renegotiation, as per official doc  SSLInsecureRenegotiation Can be disabled as below.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslinsecurerenegotiation

But we have tried this, also as default value is off it should have been disabled in first place.
can someone please let me know how to disable this on apache httpd 2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips

Answer (score 0):

There is an Option for it

SSLOptions +StrictRequire +StdEnvVars -OptRenegotiate

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions